# Parallelization in R: how to "source" on every node?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have created parallel workers (all running on the same machine) using:

```
MyCluster = makeCluster(8)
```

How can I make every of these 8 nodes source an R-file I wrote?
I tried:

```
clusterCall(MyCluster, source, "myFile.R")
clusterCall(MyCluster, 'source("myFile.R")')
```

And several similar versions. But none worked.
Can you please help me to find the mistake?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The first version should work, the second is wrong because a string isn't a function. But why do you think the first one isn't working? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code serves your purpose:

```
library(parallel)

cl <- makeCluster(4)
clusterCall(cl, function() { source("test.R") })

## do some parallel work

stopCluster(cl)
```

Also you can use `clusterEvalQ()` to do the same thing:

```
library(parallel)

cl <- makeCluster(4)
clusterEvalQ(cl, source("test.R"))

## do some parallel work

stopCluster(cl)
```

However, there is subtle difference between the two methods. `clusterCall()` runs a function on each node while `clusterEvalQ()` evaluates an expression on each node. If you have a variable list of files to source, `clusterCall()` will be easier to use since `clusterEvalQ(cl,expr)` will regard any `expr` as an expression so it's not convenient to put a variable there.

Comment: Thank you very much Ren, I successfully used your method: `clusterCall(cl, function() { source("test.R") })`

Let me only add one thing. I canged it to `output <- clusterCall(cl, function() { source("test.R") })` because otherwise it outputs me a lot of unnessasary information.

Comment: Great. `invisible(...)` will also work to prevent explicit output.

Comment: After some months I am still using this code for parallelziation. Unfortunately I have to make use of old packages from CRAN using checkpoints. I have opened another Question to discuss this connected problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37028653/r-set-checkpoint-on-worker-of-cluster

Answer (score 2):

If you use a command to source a local file, ensure the file is there.

Else place the file on a network share or NFS, and source the *absolute* path.

Better still, and standard answers, *write a package* and have that package installed on each node and then just call `library()` or `require()`.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to say that all workers are running on the same computer. They should only make use of different cores. So availibility of the files should not be an issue.

Comment: Well I think I have working examples in my 'Intro to HPC with R' slides so you can copy from there.  The issue may still be the same: different work directory for your workers.  Try an absolute path.

Comment: I sorry to ask again, but I didn't manage to "source" my files. I tried the absolute path like this:`clusterCall(MyCluster, 'source("D:/folder/file.R")')` and `clusterCall(MyCluster, source, "D:/folder/file.R")` But none worked. The first outputs me a list of function definitions that I have never seen before. The second complains that function "source("D:/folder/file.R")" cannot be found.

Comment: Maybe you want `clusterEvalQ()` instead. I can't recall, but I already pointed you to working examples (albeit older, using `snow` not `parallel`).