# R: set 'Checkpoint' on Worker of Cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, checkpoint, snow

**I use the following code to ...**
1. create a parallel cluster
2. source test.R
3. and do some parallel work with functions defined in 'test.R'

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
clusterEvalQ(cl, source("test.R"))

  ## do some parallel work

stopCluster(cl)
```

**Unfortunately I rely on old packages  :-(**
One can make use of past snapshots of the CRAN packages using 'checkpoints'

```
require(checkpoint)
checkpoint("2015-02-28")
```

**My question is ...**
how can I make use of the old packages *on* the Cluster workers?
The following does not work:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
  clusterEvalQ(cl, require(checkpoint))        # 1. load checkpoint package on workers
  clusterEvalQ(cl, checkpoint("2015-02-28"))   # 2. set the checkponit on workers
clusterEvalQ(cl, source("test.R"))

  ## do some parallel work

stopCluster(cl)
```

The command

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, require(checkpoint))
```

Returns TRUE. But the second

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, checkpoint("2015-02-28"))
```

just hangs. I don't know why the workers hang on that command. Can I somehow look into the worker to see if they are maybe just waiting for user Input or so?